# How to avoid duplication in End Result of SQL query

Tags: sql-server

```html
DECLARE @Doc INT ='21'



SELECT DISTINCT 

       [Name or title]
      ,[Subject]
      ,[Approval Description]
      ,TypeOfApproval.[Name] AS [TypeOfApproval]
      ,TypeOfExpense.[Name] AS [TypeOfExpense]
      ,ExpenseNature.[Name] AS [ExpenseNature]
      ,BudgetType.[Name] AS [BudgetType]
      ,SN.[Name] AS [Current State] 
      ,[ImageBits] AS Imj
 
  FROM [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL] Rec
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_State_Changes] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_State_Changes].[State_ID] = Rec.[State_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[ApprovalType] TypeOfApproval ON TypeOfApproval.[ID] =  [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_ApprovalType].[ApprovalType_ID]
 
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
 
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Expense] TypeOfExpense ON TypeOfExpense.[ID] = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[Nature of Expense_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense] NatureOfExpense ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Nature of Expense] ExpenseNature ON ExpenseNature.[ID] = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Nature of Expense].[Nature of Expense_ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status] ON [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status].[UBL_ID] = Rec.[ID]
  
  LEFT JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[Budget Status] BudgetType ON BudgetType.ID = [SaveImage].[dbo].[UBL_Budget Status].[Budget Status_ID]
    
  INNER JOIN [SaveImage].[dbo].[State] SN  ON Rec.[State_ID] >= SN.ID
  
  LEFT JOIN  [SaveImage].[dbo].[Img] Imj  ON Imj.[CreatorName] = SN.[Name] 
  
  WHERE  Rec.[ID] = (@Doc)
```

I want to eliminate the repeated record of the same object except one column, Because there are different values in that column and I need to get all values of that column with out duplication.

Here's a screenshot of the result I am getting now:

[image]

this is the code i am using to get the attached resultset, If i change Arithmatic Operator to '=' in the State table join it will only fetch the one result according to its current State.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: They are not duplicates, but rows with different `Current States` which single row would you like to return??

Comment: I want to return only 1 row which follows to 4 different Imj [Column] values because the record is same but have different states.

Comment: it would be better if you please could edit the post and give an expected output :)

Comment: Expected Output would be all the columns remain same except Imj column and the values of Imj column will go with column name like imj1 , imj2, imj3, imj4

Comment: I want to show the result set in a way where Image of different states like 'Initiator', 'Reviewer','Approved' when the document current state = 'Approved ' and show the result of images in separate columns of this resultset

Answer (score 0):

```
; with cte as
(
select [approval description]
       , typeofapproval
       , typeofexpense
       , expensenature
       , budgettype
       , [current state]
       , imj
       , column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key 
       , rn = row_number() over (partition by column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key order by [current state])
from table_name
)
select cte.[approval description]
       , cte.typeofapproval
       , cte.typeofexpense
       , cte.expensenature
       , cte.budgettype
       , cte.currentstate
       , cte.imj
       , cte2.imj
       , cte3.imj
       , cte4.imj
from cte
where rn = 1
left join (select imj
        from cte
        where rn = 2) cte2 on cte.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key = cte2.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key
left join (select imj
        from cte
        where rn = 3) cte3   on cte.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key = cte3.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key
left join (select imj
        from cte
        where rn = 4) cte3   on cte.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key = cte4.column_or_composition_of_columns_that_are_primary_key
```

Note that you need to partition by id in your table & join by this column too.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. Its really helpful for a beginer to learn from all of the techys like both of you out there. I am working with different joins of the tables and my result set is attched above . I need to convert a column values and evalute them into difrrent columns with the same row ID . And for this i need to use Pviot function of T-Sql . Please correct me if it could help in generating the desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this one: use DISTINCT ON (Column_Name)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON Column_1, column_2 FROM TABLE_NAME
```